# Getting element offset returns same values before setting position: absolute

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, offset, absolute

My issue is that I have 2 `<div>`s, containing the same elements. These elements are placed below each other. Upon setting the elements' `top` and `left` property to the value provided by `.offset()`, then setting the `position` to `absolute` after this, the elements' offset values are both returned as 0. Why?

```js
$(function(){
    $('[data-distance]').each(function(i,el){
        var $this = $(el),
            offset = $this.offset();
        $this.css(offset);
        $this.css('position','absolute');
    });
});
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 1000px;
    font-family: arial;
}
h1 {
    margin: 0 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-distance="1">
    <h1>Text</h1>
    <p>Assssssdddddddasdasdasdasdasdasdasdsda</p>
</div>
<div data-distance="0.5">
    <h1>Text</h1>
    <p>Assssssdddddddasdasdasdasdasdasdasdsda</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's `0` because when the first iteration of the loop happens it sets the position of the first `$('[data-distance]')` to absolute, so when the second iteration happens, the first element is at position `top: 0`, `left: 0`. Because of this, the attribute `position: absolute` should be added after finding the offset of all matched elements.

It should be like this http://jsfiddle.net/vp7jt2xj/

```
$('[data-distance]').each(function (i, el) {
    var $this = $(el),
        offset = $this.offset();    
    $this.css(offset);    
});

$('[data-distance]').css('position', 'absolute');
```

Comment: Oooh, I understand now. Thanks for the clarification. The first element is positioned absolutely, then the second jumps up.

Comment: Yes, sorry I wrote it in a hurry, I've fixed the explanation now :)